# How can I get the result $\SI{\dfrac{1}{60}}{\second}$ in siunitx package?

Tags: siunitx

I am trying to draw

[image].

I tried `$ \dfrac{1}{60}~\mathrm{s}$`.

When I try

`$\SI{\dfrac{1}{60}}{\second}$` I can not get the result. My code

```
  \documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$ \dfrac{1}{60}~\mathrm{s}$

$\SI{\dfrac{1}{60}}{\second}$
\end{document}
```

How can I get the result `$\SI{\dfrac{1}{60}}{\second}$` in siunitx package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\qty[parse-numbers=false]{\dfrac{1}{60}}{\second}
\end{document}
```

[image]